# Typescript compile errors when importing C3 and D3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, typescript, ionic-framework, c3.js

I am playing with the graphing library `C3` in an Ionic2/Angular2 typescript project. I have installed `C3` via `npm`, and the type definitions via `tsd`.

I have imported when into my own ts file as follows..

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import * as C3 from 'c3';
import * as D3 from 'd3';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/graphs-page/graphs-page.html'
 ....
})
```

All appears fine. I can see the typings for the C3 (and dependant D3), and also when I run everything seems to work.

However, when the application builds (when I run `ionic serve`), I always get the following typescript compile errors...

```
TypeScript error: D:/dev/ionic2/testcomonents/app/pages/graphs-page/graphs-page.ts(3,21): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'c3'.
TypeScript error: D:/dev/ionic2/testcomonents/app/pages/graphs-page/graphs-page.ts(4,21): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'd3'.
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I am getting these errors at build time, when I get no errors in the IDE (I am using `vscode`), and everything seems to work fine?

[EDIT]

I have since installed typescipt 2 and run with the `--traceResolution` flag. I can see that `tsc` only seems to look under various levels of `node_modules` and never looks under `typings` folder, which is where `vscode` is looking.

More confusing (to me) is how the c3.js source is included, when this is located under the node_modules/c3 folder. I have not specifically added any reference to `c3.js`, yet the graphs show up.

The settings in the `tsconfig.json` are

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "es5",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true
 },

"filesGlob": [
   "**/*.ts",
   "!node_modules/**/*"
 ],
 "exclude": [
   "node_modules",
   "typings/main",
   "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "atom": {
   "rewriteTsconfig": false
 }
}
```

I have tried various edits in the above `tsconfig.json` but cannot get it to look in the typings folder.

So my questions now become

1. How to make Typscript look in the typings folder
2. How does the the actual c3.js file located at node_modules\c3\c3.js get included in the Ionic bundle (since I have not added a reference to it anywhere)

Comment: I've gotten this error in two cases.  First, the compiler cannot find the typings.  Second, the compiler cannot find the module itself.  I am not terribly familiar with `vscode`.  Do you know if it is using SystemJS under the hood or does it have some other module resolution method?

Comment: I have found one technique which helps to debug this kind of problem.  If you upgrade to TypeScript 2.0 then you can run from the command line `tsc --traceResolution` which will print out everywhere that it is looking for your js.  It will also print out something like "found js but did not find typings" which indicates the typings are not on your path.

Comment: @pace thanks for the above. I'll get onto installing Typescript 2.0, and see if I get any extra information. As for the modules system I am not sure.... I found the statement "In Ionic 2, we get to use the magic of ES6 imports".

Answer (score 0):

I think I now know the answer to this, but if I am incorrect, please correct me!

looking in the Ionic file `D:\dev\ionic2\testcomponents\node_modules\ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript\index.js`, there is the following src property

```
var defaultOptions = {
   watch: false,
   src: ['./app/app.ts', './typings/main.d.ts'],
```

so If I add the following to `main.d.ts`

```
/// <reference path="globals/c3/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/d3/index.d.ts" />
```

the errors go away.

If I run `tsc --traceResolution` I still see errors, but my guess here is that running `tsc` from the command line does not include looking at the above Ionic script or `main.d.ts`.

To get rid of the error when using `tsc --traceResolution`, I tried added the following to the file `D:\dev\ionic2\testcomponents\node_modules\c3\package.json`

```
"typings": "../../typings/globals/c3/index.d.ts",
```

and then do the same thing for `d3`. But this then causes the following error when I run the Ionic build

```
TypeScript error: d:/dev/ionic2/testcomponents/app/pages/graphs-page/graphs-page.ts(3,21): Error TS2656: Exported external package
typings file 'd:/dev/ionic2/testcomponents/typings/globals/c3/index.d.ts' is     not a module. Please contact the package author to update the package  definition.
```

So, I think in the Ionic context, the correct thing to do is add the `///` paths to the main.d.ts file.

The other question I had, ie how is the c3.js etc file included, this is all part of the Browserfity / gulp build, and this examines everything under the nodes_modules folder. They all have the `packeage.json` file, and, in the case of c3, we have the line `"main": "c3.js"`.